# Did Chrome 61 change omnibar/omnibox behavior?

Tags: google-chrome

After updating to Google Chrome `Version 61.0.3163.79 (Official Build) (64-bit)`, I have noticed the order of results has changed.

Previously, I used to see results that I have typed most often at the top, followed by history (pages I've visited before but didn't explicitly type in the address bar).

Now the results seem to show history first and it doesn't seem to have any rhyme or reason to the results.

Example: typing `stackov` used to show my bookmark `https://stackoverflow.com` as the first hit. Now it's the last hit and the first hit is a question I must have answered.

[image: omnibar]

Was this intentionally changed to a new algorithm or is this a regression?

If it's a new algorithm, where can I read about it?

Comment: It's possible it's a bug in the new version, however, I'm unable to reproduce this behavior. Maybe other users can shed some insight on this if they also have the issue. Have you tried clearing history and cookies since the update? It's possible something to do with how they're stored was updated, or yours are corrupt.

Comment: I added a screenshot with an example of the odd behavior. I'm trying to avoid clearing history because I use my history from the omnibar all the time which is how I noticed this change.

Comment: I took a look in `chrome://flags` and found [these settings](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/293497198191050752/355438196508852237/unknown.png). I recommend toggling each setting separately until you find your old settings, if they still exist in chrome. I'd love to hear if this new behavior is a result of a newly activated flag.

Comment: @Dooley_labs [Can we please use stack.imgur in the future](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZN3z.png)

Comment: @Ramhound my apologies, I've become too accustomed to Discord's features. I'll use imgur in the future.

Comment: No one flag specified by @Dooley_labs helps... :(

Comment: Without changing any flags, I noticed it started working again. Now I'm on `Version 62.0.3202.89 (Official Build) (64-bit)`